# Django Validators

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have an Order model where I want to verify that every order's quantity doesn't exceed the actual product quantity of the product required, and I wanna achieve this by Django validators..

all of my validators for each app are being saved in a sperate file called valditaors.py now the problem, is how to pass the product model object that the Order model is referring to trough a foreign key field to the validator specified on the quantity field to verify that the product required has enough quantity and that instead of passing the actual quantity field value alone.

My Order model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name='orders') # I want to pass this product to the same validator((check_quantity_available)) specified on the next field.
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), check_quantity_available]) # in addition to this field value as well
```

My Validator:

```
def check_quantity_available(value):
    pass # how to get the product instance here throuh the Order model so I may check if it has enough quantity or not
```

Comment: If this is for a e-commerce/shopping cart, then this is the wrong approach. You want to *reserve stock*, not check if there's enough to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, race conditions aside, if you want to go with the validator, then again, as you are seeing, this is the wrong approach.

Validators validate the data itself, not the relation to other data. To validate the relation to other data, you do this is either the [form's clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/) method or the [model's clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) method.

Stock reservation is a bit bigger topic, the gist is this:

- You separate stock from product by having a Stock model, with a foreign key to the product and a quantity field
- You select the appropriate stock instance [for update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update)
- You substract the wanted quantity from the current quantity and save the stock instance
- You put the reserved quantity in the cart

You can handle abandoned carts with a periodic script to make stock available again.

This is more complex, but it prevents you selling "no":

- Bob puts 10 bread in his cart
- Anna puts 10 bread in her cart
- Bob puts other stuff in his cart
- Anna goes to checkout and pays
- Bob cannot order the bread any more, even though it's in his cart. Bob is disappointed and closes his browser.

Comment: I did a small search on periodic scripts with Django but yet things still unclear, could you suggest me tools or a link to some good topic or such a thing where I could start from? thanks..